# How to write a query to get data from entity datamodel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I want get data from one of my models. I am using Entity datamodel where I have some  tables in my Entity model. I want to select data from EmployeeTable.

```
EmployeeTable
----------------
[EmpId]|[Empname]|[EmpAddress]
```

I want to select `[EmpID]` and `[Empname]` columns from table. I don't know how to do this in Entity Framework and I have to return the data as JSON.

I had tried this methods but I am not geting the data.

How can I write the linq query?

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        int Param1;
        Param1 = 1;
        DataEntitiesModel data = new DataEntitiesModel();
        //var procedure=db.Database.SqlQuery<DataEntitiesModel>("ResourceReports @EmployeeID",new SqlParameter("@EmployeeID", Param1) );
        //var procedure = db.Database.SqlQuery<DataEntitiesModel>("Select * from EmployeeDetails");      

        return Json(procedure,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here's the model:

```
       public class DataEntitiesModel
       {      
         public Int16 EmpID{ get; set; }
         [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
         public string EmpName{ get; set; }
         [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required")]
         public string Description { get; set; }
         [Required(ErrorMessage = "Version is required")]
         public string EmpAddress{ get; set; }       
       }


     public class DataEntitiesDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<DataEntitiesModel> ProjectReports { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [nice video](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/players/PSODPlayer?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-data-i&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro) from Pluralsight to get you started with Entity Framework. You generate a data context from your database and then query this context:

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    using (var db = new DataEntitiesDBContext())
    {
        var result = db.ProjectReports.ToList().Select(e => new {
            Id = e.EmpID,
            Name = e.EmpName
        });
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```